# Trying to activate a worksheet by internal name results in Index out of range Error

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am having troubles with a very simple function in VBA:

I am working with 2 worksheets (Calculation and Plotting). So now I want to activate the worksheets when necessary with calling them by (name) and not name (specified in the properties of the sheet) to make my sheet "idiot-proof". I dont want to use the sheetname but the sheet(name) so when the User changes the sheetnames on the frontend the executed code still works.

F.e. my "Calculation" worksheet has the name "Calculation" but the (name) "calc":

`Worksheets("calc").Activate` (throws Index out Range error)

`calc.Cells()` (works just fine)

Comment: "my "Calculation" worksheet has the name "Calculation" but the (name) "calc":" ...uh, what? how did you declare `calc`?  You likely just need `Worksheets("Calculation")...`

Comment: `calc.Activate`  "codename" is the term you're missing in your question ;-)

Comment: Note though if you're using your function as a UDF it won't work...

Comment: @BruceWayne
Working with Worksheets("Calculation") is what I want to AVOID because if I give the Workbook to someone else to work with I don't want my code to stop working because the User changes the Worksheet name on the Front-End.
A sheet in VBA has 2 names:
name and (name) where name is specified in the front-end and (name) is hidden and only visible in the VBA editor (in the properties tab of the sheet)

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your fast answer! your provided solution is working fine. just one more questions: what do you mean with "codename"? (so I can specify my future questions better)

Comment: A general comment, re: "...to make my sheet 'idiot proof'"...  I might suggest simply throwing an error telling the user "Could not find `Calculation` worksheet. Please rename to continue." or something...To quote Douglas Adams, "A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools."

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for your input! I get your point and I'll keep it in mind for the future. But personally I think my wording was off and making my code independable of the front-end worksheet name is more "User-friendly", and maybe not so much "foolproof". And that's what I am trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @TimWilliams - So, even if the user renames the Worksheet "Calculation" to "ZXY", you can still refer to that sheet with `Calc.` in VBA? Can you expand on that a little, that's interesting!

Comment: @BruceWayne I found what Tim tried to tell me with `Worksheet.CodeName`. For a more detailed explanation of this read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename where it states: "It's possible for the sheet name to be different from the code name. When you create a sheet, the sheet name and code name are the same, but changing the sheet name doesn't change the code name, and changing the code name (using the Properties window in the Visual Basic Editor) doesn't change the sheet name."

Comment: Thanks for that Michael!  One final clarification - I can only assume you're actually creating the "Calculation" worksheet with VBA, yes? (e.g. `Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Calculation"`), otherwise wouldn't the CodeName be `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` (or whatever)?

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yes typically the codename for a new sheet would be (eg) `Sheet3` etc (in an English language setup).  FYI `Sheets.Add()` just returns a boolean, not a reference to the new sheet, so you can't tag on the `.Name` there: a shame since that would be more convenient.

Comment: @BruceWayne after some digging I came to this conclusion: since the `Worksheet.CodeName` property is Read-Only (as stated in the microsoft document) you cannot change the CodeName programmatically (only by hand in the properties tab in the VBA editor). So even after creating a Sheet with a desired name (f.e. `test`), the CodeName of `test` will still be `sheet1`, `sheet2`, ...

Comment: @BruceWayne You CAN however change the CodeName programmatically when you permit Access to the VBA Project (which by default is not permitted for security reasons: see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282830/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

`(name).Activate` does the trick.
In my example it would be:

`calc.Activate`

Thanks to @TimWilliams

Edit:
This Property is called `CodeName` and is read-only!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename

If you are trying to change it programmatically it throws this error:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282830/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied

Therefor it can only be changed programmatically if you permit access to the VBA Project which is not permitted by default for security reasons!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate '<- Activate sheet using the name shown outside
    ws1.Activate '<- Activate sheet using the name shown in the VBA Editor

End Sub
```